# Sending a list of assets to android wearable device

Tags: wear-os

Reading the docs (https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html), there is a method `putAsset` to transfer assets to the wear/mobile devices. I'd like to know if there is a way to transfer a list of assets instead of sending them 1 by 1. (`putStringArrayList` for a string list for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to do that one by one, there is no bulk operation for adding data items.

Comment: I am transfering a list of names and I wanted to associate each name with an image. Isn't it risky to make a loop and send a name/image? How can I know that the data will arrive in the same order I sent it?

Comment: You don't need to manage the order; each data item (asset or otherwise) has a "path" and your path can be the identifier; for example you can set the path for k-th asset to have the ending of "/images/k" so when the data item becomes available on the other end, you can identify that based on its path.

Comment: Thank you, "path" idea saved my life.